# On click only show content related to clicked title instead of opening all

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm currently working on an Angular project which uses typescript.

Inside the typescript component I have a function when on click fires a class to open a div.

My current TS is this

```
  toggleResultsMini(size: string) {
    this.showMiniResults = !this.showMiniResults;

    if (size === 'mini') {
      this.showHideMini = this.showHideMini === 'Show' ? 'Hide' : 'Show';
    } else {
      this.showHideMiniSmall =
        this.showHideMiniSmall === 'Show result'
          ? 'Hide result'
          : 'Show result';
    }
```

```
  <div class="row show-results" [ngClass]="{ 'show-results--expanded': showResults }">
    <div class="col-12 text-left">
      <div class="row result" *ngFor="let result of displayedResults.top3Mortgages | keyvalue">
        <div class="" (click)="toggleResultsMini('mini')">Click me to see</div>
        <!-- MOBILE RESULT 1 -->
        <div *ngIf="result.key == 0" class="col-12 d-block d-md-none py-3 show-mini-results" [ngClass]="{ 'show-mini-results--expanded': showMiniResults }">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">Mortgage Type</div>
              <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
                <small>{{ result.value.typeOfMortgage }}</small>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- MOBILE RESULT 3 -->
        <div *ngIf="result.key == 2" class="col-12 d-block d-md-none py-3 show-mini-results" [ngClass]="{ 'show-mini-results--expanded': showMiniResults }">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">Mortgage Type</div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
              <small>{{ result.value.typeOfMortgage }}</small>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This actually works, but it opens all divs related to that class.

How would I make this so that only the div which has been clicked opens, instead of all related divs?

Any advice would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you are making the same function call because you are binding inside an *ngFor.

You need to have some unique id per item.

Pseduo code:

```
<div *ngFor="let result of myArray">
  <div [class.expanded]="isExpanded(result.key)" (click)="toggleExpand(result.key)">
  </div>
</div>
```

In "result.key", key is some property that uniquely identified the item.

I've also simplified the html and css to distill the answer down to the key mechanisms.

As for how you manage this in the typescript, the typescript below is one option of of many ways of achieving this:

```
expandedState: {};

isExpanded(key: string): boolean {
  return !!this.expandedState[key];
}

toggleExpand(key: string): void {
  if (this.isExpanded(key)) {
    delete this.expandedState[key];
  } else {
    this.expandedState[key] = true;
  }
}
```

Your use case is more complex than my pseudo code, but the main point is that you are currently treating all divs in the same way.

Comment: Appreciate the help